# how to identify grant permission in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, i have too many tables also users to allow them to modify my data.
how can i identify or know that to which person i had grant which objects also their privileges.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/mysql-show-grants-for-all-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SHOW GRANTS
    for <user>
```

or  for all users

```
Show GRANTS
```

or for specific role

```
Show GRANTS using <role>
```